# Minimum Div Size?

Tags: html, css

I am creating a website that uses a fluid layout with artificial columns. I have an image at the top with some text to the side. I want the image to have a minimum size of 550px and a maximum size of 75% of the parent div. I tried this:

```
.class{
    width: 550px;
    maxwidth: 75%;
}
```

but it did not work.

Comment: Yes I do. I use Firefox for debugging, but much of my target audience uses IE. Much to the tune of 100%.

Comment: Wow--any idea why your users are such an IE6 crowd? W3C stats suggest only 10% still use IE6 on average.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try:

```
.class {
    min-width: 550px;
    width: 75%;
}
```

Comment: Typo. This is an IE6 error, not a CSS error. Good catch, though.

Comment: Incidentally, this article discusses getting max-width and min-width to work on IE6. I only just skimmed it, but perhaps it'll help?

http://javascript.about.com/library/blwidth.htm

Comment: Thanks for the link! I will put this JScript on my page, then test it tomorrow.

Answer (score 3):

The current CSS spec supports `min-width` and `max-width`, but not all browsers do. Namely, IE6. But most all other browsers on the market work fine.

Comment: Which is my problem. Almost all of my traffic is using IE6-. My site works perfectly in FF, but IE6/7 screws up the column and CSS alignment.

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing `maxwidth` with `max-width`.

Answer (score 0):

I know that is request is old, but this will perhaps help some other people having the same problem.

I had the same worry and this resolve it:

```
.class {    
    min-height: 300px;
    height: auto !important;
    height: 300px;
}
```